# wordpress page speed not working for desktop version

Tags: wordpress, optimization, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I did all the things Like image optimization, rendering for page speed optimization. I checked my mobile page speed increasing but desktop page speed not increasing it's still 22 again and again.  I want to know why I am facing this problem. My website is [www.sagorkhan.com](http://www.sagorkhan.com). Can anyone please help me?

**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr3Wh.png)**

Comment: [Google's PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsagorkhan.com%2F) can tell you why your site takes so long to load and how you can improve things a bit. BTW, I think [your question really doesn't belong here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Download images suggested by google (there is link down below) and replace it. Also get something like WP Super Cache that will also help massively

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors that could affect your page speed and actually I see you've done a good job so far but you may go a litter farther.

I've tested your site with [google page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.sagorkhan.com), [pingdom tool](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/entaXJ/www.sagorkhan.com), [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/sagorkhan.com/8OsLwo3V), [webpagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180506_JF_36133f8c0a2775a198403a470f220f71/1/details/) and here is my conclusion:

I guess your problem is about how to [reduce server response time](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/Server). While testing your site, it took more than 3+ seconds (6 on webpagetest) to completely load which may be considered a huge time. Reduce the server response time is not an easy task and could be a real challenge but here is a few tips:

**1. Images optimization:**

You said that you've done image optimization but still, your site have some huge images, one of them for example, is about 1MB which is can really affect the server response time. These images can be easily optimized, just go to google page speed and after you test your site scroll down and find: [Download optimized image, JavaScript, and CSS resources](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/optimizeContents?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sagorkhan.com%2F&strategy=mobile) for this page. Download the zip file and try to replace the old images with optimized ones using any FTP client, [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is more then good for that.

Note that you can find the images locations under **Optimize images** section in case you don't know the location. Repeat that step again to make sure all your images are optimized.

Also I'd recommend some plugins like [wp-smushit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/) for optimize and compress all of your images and [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to fix [Serve scaled images](https://gtmetrix.com/serve-scaled-images.html) issue. [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/) is good online alternative too if you like to do it manually.

**2. Optimize CSS Delivery**

That's not easy actually because it may requires to optimize the code and structure of your theme but you can give [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) or [W3 Total cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) a try. Both support combining and minifying all enqueued JS, and CSS files.

**3. CDNs:**

[CDN](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CDN.html) can really accelerate your site and greatly reducing your page loading time. Now, there are tons of good CDNs providers but I would recommend [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) as a start since its free and easy to use and their free plan is enough and does work really great.

**4. Caching**

WordPress caching is a must if you care about performance, I don't see any sign of caching plugins except your HTML, JavaScript, css files is minified already which is good but not enough. I would recommend [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) or [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/).

**5. Web Hosting**

If you're hosing your site in a shared host, don't hope too much to get perfect page speed even if you done all the required optimization. I'd definitely recommend upgrading to a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) since its kinda cheap (unmanaged servers can be cheaper then shared host) and not that hard to setup and secure, A small VPS server can have a significant impact on page load speed.

Answer (score -1):

You are resizing massive images using HTML/CSS when you should be resizing them individually using Photoshop or a similar image editing tool. You have a lot of render blocking js, specifically they're the YouTube scripts you're running.

Another big issue is the sheer amount of stylesheet and js files you're loading -- 19 js and 13 css. Try combining your js files together as much as you can, as well as your css files ... you're going to want to minify them as well.

You're loading many components from various sources, adding more http request overhead. If it's possible, you should consider hosting your own copies of some files.

Take a look at the output from https://gtmetrix.com/reports/sagorkhan.com/cBTMzOjD ... that should get you on the road to optimizing. Make sure you take your time reading the pagespeed and yslow tabs.

Comment: If you're using HTTP/2, I think combine or aggreate CSS/JS resources is not the best approach. Just let them in single files (and minifed) and loaded parallel.